# PIVOT data from SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following sql to monitor snowpipe usage.  Would like to pivot the field "day" but not sure how. Goal is to one row for each  table_name with row_count  for last 10 days in separate columns. Requesting assistance with this.

```
select
        table_schema_name                      ,
        table_name                             ,
        date_trunc('DAY',last_load_time) AS day,
        sum(row_count) AS row_count
FROM
        DEVDWH.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY
WHERE
        table_schema_name IN ('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2')
AND     table_catalog_name = 'DEVDWH'
AND     last_load_time     >= current_date - 10
GROUP BY
        1,2,3
```

Thank you,
gjoe

tried but seems to be not possible to meet the requirement.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-a-dynamic-PIVOT-in-Snowflake
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot

Comment: Hi - as a starting point, you’d need to generate a column with the values 1-10, to indicate the last 10 days. You need to have a constant set of values to pivot on and obviously using dates won’t give you this. Basically, use DATEDIFF on the current date and last_load_time

Answer (score 0):

Workaround implemented with help of ChatGPT

```
SELECT
    table_schema_name,
    table_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_trunc('DAY', last_load_time) = current_date - 10 THEN row_count ELSE 0 END) AS day_10,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_trunc('DAY', last_load_time) = current_date - 9 THEN row_count ELSE 0 END) AS day_9,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_trunc('DAY', last_load_time) = current_date - 8 THEN row_count ELSE 0 END) AS day_8,
    -- Add more columns for each day as needed
FROM
    DEVDWH.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY
WHERE
    table_schema_name IN ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2')
    AND table_catalog_name = 'DEVDWH'
    AND last_load_time >= current_date - 10
GROUP BY
    1, 2;
```